# Standardizing dependent and independent variable formula for ridge regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, standardization

For ridge I now that I have to standardize the the predictors before applying ridge regression. 
I want to standardize them like in  the *glmnet* function. And I don't know wich formula is used for standardization.
Should I use this: [image]  formula to standardize the *dependent(y)* variable and the *independent(x)* variable? Or this one: [image]to standardize *y* which I don't know if it is correct?

Comment: Could you explain what the second formula is trying to say?  It makes no sense: it's not a transformation of $y$ and the right side doesn't even depend on $y$.

Comment: I mistakenly rejected the edit which would have cleared up the issue that @whuber pointed out; please ignore.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: @gung thank you I didn't know that that was as an option

Comment: @whuber I edited the second formula, I got it from [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129179/why-is-glmnet-ridge-regression-giving-me-a-different-answer-than-manual-calculat) post, from the R code: **sd_y <- sqrt(var(Y)*(n-1)/n)[1,1]** and I don't know why this is done for standardization.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether $(n-1)/n$ is incorporated or not.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3931 for instance.