# lambda scaling in elastic net regression with glmnet vs sklearn

Tags: r, scikit-learn, glmnet, elastic-net

I am trying to get results to agree between glmnet and sklearn elastic net regression for a specific case where I can't normalise the response variable y. I know that for ridge regression (alpha = 0) this can be achieved by just multiplying lambda with sd(y), see eg [Why is glmnet ridge regression giving me a different answer than manual calculation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129179/why-is-glmnet-ridge-regression-giving-me-a-different-answer-than-manual-calculat)

And for pure lasso (alpha = 1) it works without rescaling the lambdas. But for the mixed case, I don't know what the proper rescaling is. I'll give an example with code below.

My question is, how can I recover the sklearn solution using glmnet in the elastic net case for an unnormalised response y?

Let's generate some mock data.

```
library(glmnet)
library(reticulate)
sklearn = import("sklearn")

X = matrix(rnorm(1e5), 1000, 100)
Y = X %*% rnorm(ncol(X)) + rnorm(nrow(X))

Xp = np_array(X, dtype = "float16")
Yp = np_array(Y, dtype = "float16")

lambda = 0.1
```

Pure ridge case (alpha = 0). Here I pass the lambda rescaled with sd(Y) to glmnet and get the same results as with sklearn with the original lambda, as expected.

```
beta_glmnet = as.numeric(glmnet(X, Y, lambda = lambda*sd(Y), alpha = 0, standardize = F, intercept = F)$beta)
beta_sklearn = as.numeric(sklearn$linear_model$ElasticNet(alpha = lambda, l1_ratio = 0, fit_intercept = FALSE)$fit(Xp, Yp)$coef_)

mean(abs(beta_glmnet))
mean(abs(beta_sklearn))
mean(abs(beta_glmnet - beta_sklearn))

# 0.622938562017786
# 0.622977211185278
# 7.33209070182556e-05
```

Pure Lasso case (alpha = 1). Here I pass the original lambda to glmnet and get the same results as with sklearn.

```
beta_glmnet = as.numeric(glmnet(X, Y, lambda = lambda, alpha = 1, standardize = F, intercept = F)$beta)
beta_sklearn = as.numeric(sklearn$linear_model$ElasticNet(alpha = lambda, l1_ratio = 1, fit_intercept = FALSE)$fit(Xp, Yp)$coef_)

mean(abs(beta_glmnet))
mean(abs(beta_sklearn))
mean(abs(beta_glmnet - beta_sklearn))

# 0.590703733705835
# 0.590713277953699
# 7.0877870919121e-05
```

Mixed case (alpha = 0.1). Here both the the glmnet results with rescaled and original lambdas differ substantially from the sklearn solution.

````
beta_glmnet1 = as.numeric(glmnet(X, Y, lambda = lambda*sd(Y), alpha = 0.1, standardize = F, intercept = F)$beta)
beta_glmnet2 = as.numeric(glmnet(X, Y, lambda = lambda, alpha = 0.1, standardize = F, intercept = F)$beta)
beta_sklearn = as.numeric(sklearn$linear_model$ElasticNet(alpha = lambda, l1_ratio = 0.1, fit_intercept = FALSE)$fit(Xp, Yp)$coef_)

mean(abs(beta_glmnet1))
mean(abs(beta_glmnet2))
mean(abs(beta_sklearn))
mean(abs(beta_glmnet1 - beta_sklearn))
mean(abs(beta_glmnet2 - beta_sklearn))

# 0.550951096753231
# 0.674230822535796
# 0.619582124477384
# 0.0686310277241525
# 0.0574189752430566
```
````