# Weird glmnet ridge regression results with an uncentered design matrix

Tags: ridge-regression, glmnet

I was recently trying to figure out what glmnet's ridge regression is doing (7,000 lines of [Fortran](https://github.com/cran/glmnet/blob/master/src/glmnet5dpclean.f#L41) are no fun) and am confused by its behavior with an **uncentered** design matrix $X$.

I am aware that there are already a lot of questions on differences between glmnet and manual implementations:

- [Why is glmnet ridge regression giving me a different answer than manual calculation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129179/why-is-glmnet-ridge-regression-giving-me-a-different-answer-than-manual-calculat)
- [Ridge regression results different in using lm.ridge and glmnet](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74206/ridge-regression-results-different-in-using-lm-ridge-and-glmnet)
- [What are the differences between Ridge regression using R's glmnet and Python's scikit-learn?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160096/what-are-the-differences-between-ridge-regression-using-rs-glmnet-and-pythons)

The solution usually is that someone forgot to scale $\lambda$ by a factor of $\frac{1}{N}$ or forgot that $y$ is standardized.

However, I try to understand how glmnet handles design matrices with `colMeans(X) != 0`.
I wrote a small script to demonstrate the problem, where I compare my manual implementation with the `penalized` and the `glmnet` packages:

```r
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
set.seed(1)

# Create some dummy data
y <- rnorm(n = 2000)
y <- scale(y)
# not centered on purpose
X <- matrix(rnorm(n = 10 * 2000, mean = 100), nrow = 2000, ncol = 10)
lambda <- 5

# Ridge regression with glmnet
glmnet_fit <- glmnet::glmnet(X, y, family = "gaussian", lambda = lambda, alpha = 0, 
                             standardize = FALSE, intercept = FALSE)
glmnet_coef <- as.numeric(glmnet_fit$beta)

# Ridge via normal equations
manual_coef <- c(solve(t(X) %*% X + diag(lambda * nrow(X), nrow = ncol(X))) %*% t(X) %*% y)

# Ridge with penalized package
penalized_fit <- penalized::penalized(y, penalized = X, unpenalized = ~ 0,
                                      lambda1 = 0, lambda2 = lambda * nrow(X))
#> 12
penalized_coef <- penalized::coef(penalized_fit)

# Compare the results
plot(penalized_coef, manual_coef, main = "Manual vs penalized\non uncentered X"); abline(0,1)
plot(penalized_coef, glmnet_coef, main = "glmnet vs penalized\non uncentered X"); abline(0,1)
```

[image]

```r
##### Normalized X

X_norm <- scale(X)

# Ridge regression with glmnet
glmnet_fit <- glmnet::glmnet(X_norm, y, family = "gaussian", lambda = lambda, alpha = 0, 
                             standardize = FALSE, intercept = FALSE)
glmnet_coef <- as.numeric(glmnet_fit$beta)

# Ridge via normal equations
manual_coef <- c(solve(t(X_norm) %*% X_norm + diag(lambda * nrow(X), nrow = ncol(X))) %*% t(X_norm) %*% y)

# Ridge with penalized package
penalized_fit <- penalized::penalized(y, penalized = X_norm, unpenalized = ~ 0,
                                      lambda1 = 0, lambda2 = lambda * nrow(X))
#> 12
penalized_coef <- penalized::coef(penalized_fit)

# Compare the results
plot(penalized_coef, manual_coef, main = "Manual vs penalized\non scaled X"); abline(0,1)
plot(penalized_coef, glmnet_coef, main = "glmnet vs penalized\non scaled X"); abline(0,1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As you can see, for **centered** $X$ the results agree between all three approaches, however for **uncentered** $X$ glmnet is doing something different. (I also did check the behavior with `standardize = TRUE`, but that doesn't change the problem.)

If anyone has some insight on what I missed or what glmnet is doing internally, I would be very thankful :)

Comment: `glmnet` *always* includes an intercept term.

Comment: But what does `intercept = FALSE` do then?

Comment: As far as I can tell it doesn't do anything--in all my uses of `glmnet` I have been unable to remove the intercept.

Comment: Well, as `y` is always centered and scaled to unit-variance, for a centered `X` it makes hardly a difference a difference if you include the intercept. However for uncentered `X` the coefficients differ depending on `intercept`:
y <- rnorm(2000); 
X <- matrix(rnorm(n = 2*2000, mean = rep(c(100, 500), each = 2000)), ncol = 2); 
coef(glmnet(X, y, alpha = 0, lambda = lambda, intercept = TRUE, standardize = FALSE)); 
#> 2.786449671  0.015280834 -0.008664797; 
coef(glmnet(X, y, alpha = 0, lambda = lambda, intercept = FALSE, standardize = FALSE)); 
#> 0.000000e+00 -1.761616e-04 -1.406650e-06