# What is the recommend function for Ridge regression

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, ridge-regression

The following [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74206/ridge-regression-results-different-in-using-lm-ridge-and-glmnet) is an answer for why `lm.ridge` and `glmnet` results are different and how to solve that. My question is different since I am asking which functions are more trusted to use because they are giving different results each time when compared with textbook calculation.

I am working with ridge regression in R. I have three functions to use which are `glmnet` or `lm.ridge` or textbook calculation.

I can make the `glmnet` results as textbook calculation results.

```
p.tmp <- 5
n.tmp <- 30

set.seed(123)
X=scale(matrix(rnorm(n.tmp*p.tmp),ncol = p.tmp))
Y=scale(rnorm(n.tmp))

set.seed(123) 
ridge.fit.cv <- cv.glmnet(X, Y, alpha = 0, standardize = FALSE, intercept = FALSE)
ridge.fit.lambda <- ridge.fit.cv$lambda.1se
ridge_mod <- coef(glmnet(X, Y, alpha=0, standardize = FALSE,   lambda = ridge.fit.lambda) )[-1]
###############################
ridge.coef.DEF = solve(t(X) %*% X + n.tmp* ridge.fit.lambda * diag(p.tmp)) %*% t(X) %*% Y
cbind(glmnet=c(ridge_mod),textbook=c(ridge.coef.DEF), lm.ridge=c(coef( lm.ridge(Y~X - 1, lambda=ridge.fit.lambda))))
```

The results as follows

```
          glmnet      textbook     lm.ridge
X1  3.040157e-04  3.092039e-04  0.009102455
X2  9.805261e-04  9.972422e-04  0.028596273
X3  1.514714e-04  1.540631e-04  0.004855324
X4  1.721871e-04  1.751177e-04  0.004789519
X5 -4.282657e-05 -4.355457e-05 -0.001143931
```

Or I can also make `lm.ridge` results as textbook calculation as giving below

```
set.seed(123) 
ridge.fit.cv <- cv.glmnet(X, Y, alpha = 0, standardize = FALSE, intercept = FALSE)
ridge.fit.lambda <- ridge.fit.cv$lambda.1se
ridge_mod <- coef(glmnet(X, Y, alpha=0, standardize = FALSE,   lambda = ridge.fit.lambda) )[-1]
###############################
ridge.coef.DEF = solve(t(X) %*% X + ridge.fit.lambda * diag(p.tmp)) %*% t(X) %*% Y
cbind(glmnet=c(ridge_mod),textbook=c(ridge.coef.DEF), lm.ridge=c(coef( lm.ridge(Y~X - 1, lambda=ridge.fit.lambda*(30/29)))))
```

The results as

```
          glmnet     textbook     lm.ridge
X1  3.040157e-04  0.008815056  0.008815056
X2  9.805261e-04  0.027715213  0.027715213
X3  1.514714e-04  0.004692398  0.004692398
X4  1.721871e-04  0.004649196  0.004649196
X5 -4.282657e-05 -0.001112091 -0.001112091
```

****My question is which method I should believe because as you notice the results are different.****

Should I make the text calculation as `glmnet` or as `lm.ridge`?

Comment: Your edited question does not appear to have any foundation.  The results table at the end shows that `textbook` and `lm.ridge` agree to eight decimal places (maybe the textbook used `lm.ridge`!) and the duplicate explains why `glmnet` should *not* agree with the others.

Comment: Yes, you are right and this is the reason for my question. Based on this difference which functions someone should use and trust with the Ridge regression. Bear in mind that the textbook is also shown to be approximate as glmnet. Also, lambda in lm.ridge is multiplied by (n/n-1) to have the same eight decimal places. So, the question is still open to hearing from other experts in the field.

Comment: I still don't understand what your question is.  It seems to be asking for software recommendations, but those aren't on topic here.

Comment: The software is only for clarification. I am not asking for a code edit. The R- function is usually related to theoretical work.